# urlopen error An error occured while connecting to the server: ApplicationError: 2 [Errno 10104] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am getting this URLError while using it from Google AppEngine app. However the same python script works fine when run as standalone script. I searched a lot in the internet but couldn't get the solution for this. Has anyone encountered this and resolved it successfully?

```
response = opener.open(req)
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 394, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 412, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1207, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1174, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: urlopen error An error occured while connecting to the server: ApplicationError: 2 [Errno 10104] getaddrinfo failed

Comment: This is usually indicative of a DNS issue. Is the URL you are trying to fetch local to your network? Are the DNS settings properly set for public viewing on the URL?

Comment: @someone1, how does one check those settings?  I'm having this issue as well when I try to deploy (    \google_appengine\lib\fancy_urllib\fancy_urllib\__init__.py", line 383, in do_open
    raise url_error
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
).

Comment: From your PC, try to ping the domain of the URL you are trying to reach. If you can, then its accessible to you. Now try the same thing on a website like http://ping.eu/ping/, if you can't, then the location of the URL is most likely a local one. Although there is the chance the host won't respond to pings. Any host you are trying to access in your network from your app needs to be accessible from a public address for your app to work.